# Check name of file try_files

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to check if a file exists but the URL is not the same as the file's name. I mean, my URL is:

```
localhost/12/569.jpg?od=3
```

And I want to check if the file v12t569.jpg exists throught try_files on ngingx. Is it possible?

```
try_files /files/img/$uri ;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
location ~ ^/(\d+)/(\d+\.jpg)$ {
    root /files/img;
    try_files /v$1t$2 =404;
}
```

- http://nginx.org/r/location
- http://nginx.org/r/root
- http://nginx.org/r/try_files
- man pcresyntax
- man pcrepattern